# Ubuntu server refused my SSH key, what might I be missing?

Tags: ssh

My root user can login using ssh but for some reason my newuser can't login using the same key.  I'm using putty and these are the messages I got.

Console message: `Using username 'newuser'. Server refused our key`

Putty Message: `Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)`

I also tried logging into my root account and switching users. I used `ssh newuser@my.ip.address` and no luck.  I got this message, `Permission denied (publickey).`

On my server I created a key file here `/home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` and I pasted my SSH key into that file.  In addition I've browsed on my windows machine and attached the file in putty.

I'm pulling my hair out.  I'm not quite sure where to look to find the problem.  Is there something obvious I might be missing?

**-- update --**
When I enter this `namei -l /home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` this is my output.

`f: /home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxr-xr-x newuser  newuser  newuser
drwx------ newuser  newuser  .ssh
-rw------- root root authorized_keys`

Comment: You want multiple accounts to use the same key?

Comment: It's actually just me trying out my root and a test user account from the same windows machine.  So for this it's ok.  Unless for some reason that doesn't work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `namei -l /home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks so much I updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem may be your authorized_keys file is owned by `root:root` and I believe this should be owned by the username of the user who will be connecting (`username:username`).

SSH checks ownership and permissions of the `.ssh` folder and the files within it for security reasons.  While not every deviation from the normal ownership and permissions may result in a security hole, there are some ways to create a security hole this way, and SSH errs on the side of being pedantic.  Furthermore, while the SSH server daemon needs to run as root, it's possible that it forks and drops to the regular user account before it starts verifying the key, meaning that the authorized_keys file wouldn't be visible to it.

Comment: Being a noob I believe I have 2 authorized_keys files.  One for each user.  Should I only have 1 file?

Comment: You have one for each user you want to connect as.  Each one should go in `/home/username/.ssh/` except root's which goes in `/root/.ssh/`, and each should be owned by that user and have permissions 0600.

Comment: Holy smokes you might be right. I think I created my newuser `authorized_keys` file when I was logged into root.  Time to do some checking.

Comment: You were 100% correct.  I used `chown` to change ownership to newuser and the problem was fixed on the spot.